# Relation between the weighted matrix norm and the weights

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

For a nonsingular matrix $W \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times{}m}$, the weighted vector norm is defined as $||\overrightarrow{x}||_W = ||W\overrightarrow{x}||$. Let $||A||$ denote the induced matrix norm by the original vector norm $||\overrightarrow{x}||$, and $||A||_W$ denote the induced matrix norm by the weighted vector norm $||\overrightarrow{x}||_W$. Prove that if $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times{}m}$ then $||A||_W = ||WAW^{-1}||$.

Comment: Hello, R.K. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, excellent advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition
$$
\|A\|_W=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|WAx\|}{\|Wx\|}=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|WAW^{-1}(Wx)\|}{\|Wx\|}.
$$
But as $W$ is non-singular
$$
\big\{Wx:x\in\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}\big\}=\big\{y:y\in\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}\big\},
$$
and hence
$$
\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|WAW^{-1}(Wx)\|}{\|Wx\|}=\sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{\|WAW^{-1}y\|}{\|y\|}=\|WAW^{-1}\|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of Proof:
\begin{align}
\|A\|_W&=\sup_{\|x\|_W\leq1}\|Ax\|_W\\
&=\sup_{\|Wx\|\leq1} \|WAx\|\\
&=\sup_{\|y\|\leq1} \|WAW^{-1}y\|\\
\\&=\|WAW^{-1}\|
\end{align}